# JBoss WildFly 8.1.0 GA Infinite redeploy

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I'm using JBoss WildFly 8.1.0 GA and when i started my application (with jdk1.8.0_05 or jdk1.8.0_45 - I tried both) the war is reployed over and over again (infinite redeploys). I don't have any application error/exception on this process.

As workaround I updated the standalone\configuration\standalone.xml to deploy a non-exploded war (auto-deploy-exploded="false"). Something like:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
<deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
</subsystem>
```

I also try to change the Jboss configurations like, Publishing, Deployment Scanner, and so on... always without success.

Someone face the same problem? Any solution?

Comment: Does your application write to itself during startup?

Comment: No, i.e, i guess that in some point some file is being updated and that's the reason for this behavior. But i didn't find any...